# Setting up Blender headless rendering inside an Ubuntu docker image on a server

Tags: rendering, command-line

Recently I got access to my college server and I want to set up headless rendering for my blender projects in  the server.

The issue is, they have given me a docker image with Ubuntu 19.10.
I tried rendering in it, but I faced a lot of issues:

- rendering with "-b" flag didn't help. It threw "unable to open a display error".
- I tried setting up x11 forwarding with ssh but there are some problems because of it being a docker image.
- Compiling from the source code is **not** possible because the server has a PowerPC 64-bit little endian architecture and there are lots of problem in building the dependencies for compiling the code. I already tried it and failed miserably :(

So, what would be the best method to set up the headless renderer?

Answer (score 1):

Check out my self answered question here: [How do you use Eevee renderer in a Docker container using bpy?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/232961/how-do-you-use-eevee-renderer-in-a-docker-container-using-bpy/232962#232962)

Basically what you should do is install `xvfb` as a framebuffer on the server. It works, but I caution you that in my experience it's so much less efficient than a real display that you're better off simply switching to Cycles rendering.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I already gave up on setting up the headless renderer and moved on xD. So there's no way for me to verify if this works. If someone bumps into this in the future, I hope this helps them